# How to access Parent Element from json object using Vuejs

Tags: json, vue.js

I'm very new at Vue.js and i'm trying to access a data from an api. I got some JSON data and i want to access my sensors id's. But sensor id's doesn't have any name. For example, this is my data:

```
{
   "SID":"valid"
}{
   "alarms":1598532382,
   "chanscan":1,
   "cloud_config":1579015363,
   "cloud_credentials":1,
   "cloud_status":1,
   "currData":1598532382,
   "favourites":1579015363,
   "hardware":1597737383,
   "oldestRecords":1,
   "scanreq":1,
   "sensors_raw":1598270610,
   "settings_raw":1597740959,
   "users":1597740912
}1598532408{
   "1053397":{
      "time":1598531818,
      "t":30.15,
      "h":42,
      "lost":0,
      "rssi":-67,
      "volt":1.48,
      "ptype":6,
      "grey":0,
      "vari":9
   },
   "3146177":{
      "time":1598532123,
      "t":30.15,
      "h":43,
      "p":100070,
      "co2":609,
      "co2Abc":0,
      "lost":0,
      "rssi":-58,
      "volt":1.56,
      "ptype":13,
      "grey":0,
      "vari":16
   },
   "4195593":{
      "time":1598107788,
      "C":103,
      "lost":0,
      "rssi":-71,
      "volt":3.06,
      "ptype":13,
      "vari":2,
      "t":null,
      "h":null,
      "p":null,
      "co2":null,
      "co2Abc":null
   },
   "6292226":{
      "time":1598532029,
      "t":25.7,
      "bec":0.0247,
      "pec":0.961,
      "dp":5.555887,
      "vwc":0.093,
      "lost":0,
      "rssi":-62,
      "volt":1.44,
      "ptype":20,
      "grey":0,
      "vari":1
   },
   "lastRx":1598532123,
   "missing":1,
   "paired":4
}{
   "1053397":{
      "humi":{
         "type":"humi",
         "since":1598346415,
         "desc":"threshumiover",
         "value":42,
         "diff":12
      }
   },
   "4195593":{
      "rssi":{
         "type":"fatal",
         "desc":"packetslost",
         "since":1598107786
      }
   }
}
```

What can I do to access the "1598532408", "3146177" and "1053397" values so I can display them in the left column of a table? Example of my vue.js table:

```
<tr v-for="sensor in list" v-bind:key="sensor">
        <td>{{sensor}}</td>
        <td>{{sensor.time}}</td>
      </tr>
```

Using {{sensor}} gives me all of my data.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated here. I'll have to redo some of this once they actually get the data right, but for now, this is sort of what I'm working with.

Comment: Can you provide what you have in `list` do you have sensor id in your fetched data?

Comment: No, I want to share what you get when you do `{{list}}` in your template, don't need for all data.

Comment: Same thing : `{ "auth": { "SID": "valid" }, "modified": { "alarms": 1598535885, "chanscan": 1, "cloud_config": 1579015363, "cloud_credentials": 1, "cloud_status": 1, "currData": 1598535885, "favourites": 1579015363, "hardware": 1597737383, "oldestRecords": 1, "scanreq"...., "grey": 0, "vari": 9 ..... } }`